# New user account - permission denied to enter a docker

Tags: docker, user-accounts, redcap

I work on a server (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-40-generic x86_64)).
Somebody else set-up some folders and mysql data bases in a docker *redcap-lamp* on this server.
In addition, he created a user account for me to enter the server, and the docker.

Every thing works fine with my account.
As login on the server I use: `ssh [my user account]@[our server]`.
To enter the docker I (was told to) use: `docker exec -it redcap-lamp bash`.

I now had to create a user account for somebody else (and am not used to working in terminals and dockers).

I created a new user account by using: `sudo adduser [newUser]`, what worked fine.
It is possible to log in with this new account to have access to our server.
Unfortunately, when I use `docker exec -it redcap-lamp bash` to enter the docker with the new account, the permission is always denied. I get the output:

`Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/redcap-lamp/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`

Do I have to give new users some 'privileges' or something? Does anybody know where the problem lies and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the new username in the docker group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker <newUser>
```

Check if the user was added:

```
cat /etc/group | grep docker
```

Log as the new user and check if you still face the problem

Comment: I'm glad I could help. You may accept / up-vote if the answer if it was accurate and answered your question, to help other users that have similar issues. Thanks!

Comment: As stated in my answer: Be carefull as it will increase your attack surface on your Docker daemon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `docker` group and add the user to it https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

**Warning**: It will increase your attack surface. As you are new to docker, I advise you to take info about the risks from the `Somebody else` if possible.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't understand, why I need to enable my user to enter the docker. Since I created the user by using: ```sudo adduser ...```, I thought my user has admin privileges...? Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: `sudo adduser` creates a basic user. It does not have any particular permissions. You add permissions afterward by puting this user in groups. `sudo` means that you use `root` to create the user but not that the user behaves as root.