# Mac TestContainer Minikube - Error - "Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration"

Tags: docker, minikube, testcontainers

I am trying to get test containers (java, oracle) working on my macbook pro (intel). It was working fine with Docker Desktop until it started failing due to space issues which I could not figure out.

Hence, I removed Docker Desktop and instead installed minikube. I have tried setting up minikube  twice with 2 different drivers -

- hyperkit
- docker

I continue to get same exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.lambda$getFirstValidStrategy$7(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:277)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:268)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:152)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:194)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory$1.getDockerClient(DockerClientFactory.java:106)
    at com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClientDelegate.authConfig(DockerClientDelegate.java:109)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:332)
```

Here's how I have configured minikube using both drivers.

**Using hyperkit**

```
minikube start --container-runtime=hyperkit --vm=true
eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
```

**Using docker**

```
minikube start --container-runtime=docker --vm=true
eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
```

I have also configured `.testcontainer.properties` as below

```
docker.client.strategy = org.testcontainers.dockerclient.UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy
testcontainers.reuse.enable = true
docker.host=tcp\://192.168.64.2\:2376
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a missing permission for a minikube user, try running the following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker <newUser>

sudo usermod -aG docker minikube

cat /etc/group | grep docker
```

You may also see following links that can be related or helpful with your issue

- [Could not find a valid Docker environment](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/613#issuecomment-375671713)
- [New user account - permission denied to enter a docker [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63070313/new-user-account-permission-denied-to-enter-a-docker)